# How do I find this string?

Tags: regex, find

I'm trying to match these file names with the find command:

```
4702011-10-21CR719557-R85262-ALPHA.jar
4702011-10-21CR719557-R85262-BETA.jar
```

I'm reasonable familiar with Java-Perl regex syntax. Unfortunately, find only supports emacs and posix syntax.

Even after looking at the emacs syntax I cannot get a basic match to work.

```
find . -regex "^[[:digit:]]+" -- matches nothing
find . -regex "^[[:digit:]]+.*(ALPHA\|BETA)\.jar" -- matches nothing
```

This is pretty straightforward in Java and Perl, for example:

```
ls | grep -P "^\d+.*(ALPHA|BETA)\.jar"
```

works.

Comment: I added an grep using Perl regex as an example of what I want.

Comment: I can only give one correct answer, though everyone was correct. Thanks.

Comment: For your amusement the complete command:find . -regextype posix-awk -regex ".*/[0-9\-]+CR[0-9]+-R[0-9]+-(ALPHA|BETA)\.jar" ! \( -name \*689305\* \) -exec java -jar {} --describe \; | grep "^CR" | sort | uniq

Answer (score 2, accepted):

a regex for matching those files with either posix-awk or posix-extended regxtype would be:

```
find . -regextype posix-awk -regex ".*/[[:digit:]]+-[[:digit:]]+-[A-Z0-9]+-[A-Z0-9]+-(ALPHA|BETA)\.jar"
```

because find -regex does matches, not searches

you can specify regex type with -regextype. see the manpage of your find implementation to check what regex engines are supported.

sample (get the files no matter the dir depth):

```
root@smgw:/tmp# ls -1
4702011-10-21CR719557-R85262-ALPHA.jar
4702011-10-21CR719557-R85262-BETA.jar
one
root@smgw:/tmp# find . -regextype posix-awk -regex ".*/[[:digit:]]+-[[:digit:]]+-[A-Z0-9]+-[A-Z0-9]+-(ALPHA|BETA)\.jar"
./4702011-10-21CR719557-R85262-ALPHA.jar
./4702011-10-21CR719557-R85262-BETA.jar
```

move the jars around, make sure they're still returned

search them with an abs path

```
root@smgw:/tmp# find /tmp  -regextype posix-awk -regex ".*/[[:digit:]]+-[[:digit:]]+-[A-Z0-9]+-[A-Z0-9]+-(ALPHA|BETA)\.jar"
/tmp/4702011-10-21CR719557-R85262-ALPHA.jar
/tmp/4702011-10-21CR719557-R85262-BETA.jar
```

modified depth:

```
root@smgw:/tmp# mkdir -p x/y/z
root@smgw:/tmp# cp *^C
root@smgw:/tmp# mv *.jar x/y/z/
root@smgw:/tmp# find /tmp  -regextype posix-awk -regex ".*/[[:digit:]]+-[[:digit:]]+-[A-Z0-9]+-[A-Z0-9]+-(ALPHA|BETA)\.jar"
/tmp/x/y/z/4702011-10-21CR719557-R85262-ALPHA.jar
/tmp/x/y/z/4702011-10-21CR719557-R85262-BETA.jar
```

Answer (score 3):

A regex using emacs style to match your pattern could be:

```
".*/[0-9]+-[0-9]+-[0-9A-Z]+-[0-9A-Z]+-\(ALPHA\|BETA\)\.jar$"
```

Below is a simple test I've made:

```
abarbosa@SPF-157:~/Temp/test$ ls -1
4702011-10-21CR719557-R85262-ALPHA.jar
4702011-10-21CR719557-R85262-BETA.jar
whatever.jar
abarbosa@SPF-157:~/Temp/test$ find . -regex ".*/[0-9]+-[0-9]+-[0-9A-Z]+-[0-9A-Z]+-\(ALPHA\|BETA\)\.jar$"
./4702011-10-21CR719557-R85262-BETA.jar
./4702011-10-21CR719557-R85262-ALPHA.jar
```

Answer (score 1):

According to the [`man find`](http://linux.die.net/man/1/find), this is a match on **the whole path**, not a search. So, you must use something like this:

```
$ find . -regex .*/[0-9]+.*\.jar
```

You can also change the regular expression type to posix-awk, posix-basic, posix-extended, ... with the `-regextype` option.

Comment: That regex gives me jars that don't start with digits. Imagine there are dozens of jars in the directory, I only want to match the ones that start with 470 something.

Comment: Just insert a leading slash before the 470... Updated my answer.